# Is there an easy way to establish a hierarchy between entities using only 2 ID fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with 2 fields like so:

| Account_ID | Parent_ID |
| --- | --- |
| x | y |
| x1 | y |
| x2 | y |
| y | z |
| y1 | z |
| y2 | z |
| z | z |
| z | a |
| z1 | a |
| a | a |
| b | b |

The IDs fields are both in int64 format. The first field represents accounts which could be controlled by a parent account which could be itself controlled by another parent account. For example: A controls Z who controls Y who controls X.

Not sure if this is relevant but for full context, it is possible for a parent to not actually use their own accounts for personal purpose and only use it to manage their children accounts. For example: Y falls under this scenario because it does not have a row relating it to itself like Z & A.

I am trying to create a field like in the table below that would easily highlight the structure of that hierarchy:

| Account_ID | Parent_ID | Hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | x/y/z/a |
| x1 | y | x1/y/z/a |
| x2 | y | x2/y/z/a |
| y | z | x/y/z/a |
| y1 | z | y1/z/a |
| y2 | z | y2/z/a |
| z | z | x/y/z/a |
| z | a | x/y/z/a |
| z1 | a | z1/a |
| a | a | x/y/z/a |
| b | b | b |

The one & two tiered ones are fairly simple with a concatenate, but I was wondering if there is an elegant way to populate the multi-tiered ones like "x/y/z/a"?

Comment: This is a basic graph relationship.  Existing graph packages and algorithms will solve your pathfinding problems.

Comment: Your z has two parents. How to decide which one to take?

Comment: @Prune I'm not familiar with the graph packages, do you have one in that you can suggest? I'm looking to learn how to tackle these issues more effectively.

Comment: @PeterJulian did you mean the row where it says |z|z|? If so its because it is possible for a parent to also use & control their accounts on their own like Z & A and vice-versa like with Y where it doesn't have a row like that

Comment: Asking for references and recommendations is specifically off topic.  Search "Python graph package".  The choice depends on what you want to do with the package after this.  That said, `networkx` handles my simple needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick. Advantageously it only relies on pandas and a small function.

```py
def add_hierarchy(df, s, tier):
    df['Hierarchy'] = df['Account_ID']
    for i in range(tier):
        next_tier = s.apply(lambda x: df[df['Account_ID'] == x].iloc[0])
        df['Hierarchy'] += '/' +  next_tier['Account_ID']
        s = next_tier['Parent_ID']



add_hierarchy(df, df['Parent_ID'], tier=3)
```

Probably you may want to add some sort of nice format afterwards. However, it returns the correct hierarchies

```
  Account_ID Parent_ID Hierarchy
0          x         y   x/y/z/a
1         x1         y  x1/y/z/a
2         x2         y  x2/y/z/a
3          y         z   y/z/a/a
4         y1         z  y1/z/a/a
5         y2         z  y2/z/a/a
6          z         a   z/a/a/a
7         z2         a  z2/a/a/a
8          a         a   a/a/a/a
9          b         b   b/b/b/b
```

(Please check your output. z has two parents given. I assumed z to have only one parent to be deterministic as is also indicated in your example output.)

Comment: Had some issues with the index on this one but it pointed me in the right direction thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also go a long way and write a function to do this:

```
def relation(data, sep = '/'):
    def _relation (x, v, m = None):
        if m is None:
            m = [x]
        n =  np.unique(v[np.in1d(v[:,0], x), 1])
        m.extend(n)
        if np.any(n==x):
            return m[:-1]
        else:
            return _relation(n, v, m)
    dat = np.array(data)[:, :2]
    key = np.unique(dat[:,0])
    dc = {}
    while len(key)>0:
        rels = _relation(key[0], dat)
        result = sep.join(rels)
        for val in rels:
            if not dc.get(val, False):
                dc[val] = result
        key = key[~np.in1d(key, rels)]
    dc = pd.Series(dc, name = 'Hierarchy', 
              index = pd.Index(dc.keys(),
                               name = data.columns[0]))
    return pd.merge(data, dc.reset_index())

print(relation(df))

  Account_ID Parent_ID Hierarchy
0          x         y   x/y/z/a
1         x1         y  x1/y/z/a
2         x2         y  x2/y/z/a
3          y         z   x/y/z/a
4         y1         z    y1/z/a
5         y2         z    y2/z/a
6          z         z   x/y/z/a
7          z         a   x/y/z/a
8         z1         a      z1/a
9          b         b         b
```

Comment: I tried turning this into a loop as running it as it was hitting the recursion limits with the dataset having over 300K rows